# mongoose schema multi ref for one property

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema, ref

How to write multi ref for one property of one mongoose schema, like this(but wrong):

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var PeopleSchema = new Schema({
    peopleType:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: ['A', 'B'] /*or 'A, B'*/
    }
})
```

Comment: This doesn't really make sense as how would Mongoose know which model to reference for a given doc? Can you provide some more details on what you're trying to do?

Comment: Thanks.OK,for example, I have two types of goods, AGoods model and BGoods model.And I also have a Goods model to save all of them(only save ref).So when I find a good, I will search in Goods model, and then if find ,it will populate the real good information from AGoods or BGoods.

Comment: did you find a way to do this?

Answer (score 40):

You should add string field to your model and store external model name in it,  and refPath property  - [Mongoose Dynamic References](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref)

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var PeopleSchema = new Schema({
    externalModelType:{
        type: String
    },
    peopleType:{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        refPath: 'externalModelType'
    }
})
```

Now Mongoose will populate peopleType with object from corresponding model.

Comment: So he should add two string fields to reference two models A and B?

Answer (score 6):

In the current version of Mongoose i still don't see that multi ref possible with syntax like you want. But you can use part of method "Populating across Databases" described [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html). We just need to move population logic to explicitly variant of population method:

```
var PeopleSchema = new Schema({
    peopleType:{
        //Just ObjectId here, without ref
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true,
    },
    modelNameOfThePeopleType:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.String, required: true
    }
})

//And after that
var People = mongoose.model('People', PeopleSchema);
People.findById(_id)
    .then(function(person) {
        return person.populate({ path: 'peopleType',
            model: person.modelNameOfThePeopleType });
    })
    .then(populatedPerson) {
        //Here peopleType populated
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using Dynamic References via refPath

```
const commentSchema = new Schema({
body: { type: String, required: true },
doc: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true,
    // Instead of a hardcoded model name in `ref`, `refPath` means Mongoose
    // will look at the `docModel` property to find the right model.
    refPath: 'docModel'
},
docModel: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ['BlogPost', 'Product']
}
```

});

Gotten from mongoose docs, [Link to mongoose docs for dynamic references via refPath](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#dynamic-ref)